# Convert table to dataframe and have the exact style / layout

Tags: r, dataframe

Table looks like this:

```
> xtabs(~gear+am,mtcars)
    am
gear  0  1
   3 15  0
   4  4  8
   5  0  5
>
```

data frame version looks like:

```
> as.data.frame.matrix(xtabs(~gear+am,mtcars))
   0 1
3 15 0
4  4 8
5  0 5
>
```

I'm losing `gear` and `am`.

I could go caveman style: and it add "gear" to position 1,1 and then rbind "am". Is there a better way?

Comment: `read.table(text = capture.output(xtabs(~gear+am,mtcars)), fill = TRUE)` is close. there is also `ftable` and `write.ftable` which are similar

Comment: that was the closest but: "have the exact style / layout" . Thank u all so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?

```
library(tidyverse)
data.frame(xtabs(~gear + am, mtcars)) %>% 
    mutate(am = paste0("am", am)) %>% 
    spread(am, Freq)

  gear am0 am1
1    3  15   0
2    4   4   8
3    5   0   5
```

Answer (score 0):

Also not identical, but gives the same meaning.

```
r.t <- xtabs(~ gear + am, mtcars)
r.d <- as.data.frame.matrix(r)
rownames(r.d) <- paste0(names(dimnames(r.t))[1], dimnames(r.t)[[1]])
colnames(r.d) <- paste0(names(dimnames(r.t))[2], dimnames(r.t)[[2]])
r.d

#       am0 am1
# gear3  15   0
# gear4   4   8
# gear5   0   5
```